# объясните работу кода

Tags: javascript

подскажите как работает этот код:

```
function buildCoveTicketMaker( transport ) {
    return function ( name ) {
        alert("Here is your transportation ticket via the " + transport + ".\n" +
                "Welcome to the Cold Closures Cove, " + name + "!");
    }
}

var getSubmarineTicket = buildCoveTicketMaker("Submarine");
var getBattleshipTicket = buildCoveTicketMaker("Battleship");
var getGiantSeagullTicket = buildCoveTicketMaker("Giant Seagull");

console.log(getSubmarineTicket("Mario"));
console.log(getBattleshipTicket("Luigi"));
console.log(getGiantSeagullTicket("Bowser"));
```

суть в том, что я не понимаю, почему и как подставляется имя в переменную `name` внутри функции, когда я ее вызываю `getSubmarineTicket("Mario")`.

Comment: `buildCoveTicketMaker` возвращает анонимную (безымянную) функцию, вы ее вызываете типередаете в нее аргумент `"Mario"`.

Comment: @Nofate, у нас вроде был вопрос про замыкания?

Comment: да, никак не пойму как работуют эти замыкания: здесь я понимаю var getSubmarineTicket = buildCoveTicketMaker("Submarine");  Submarine - попадает в function buildCoveTicketMaker( transport ) . а вот как Mario попадает в name не могу понять?

Comment: @stas.t, в комментарии выше как раз ссылка на такой же вопрос, с объяснениями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

функция `buildCoveTicketMaker` - возвращает функцию принимающую один параметр `name`.

```
return function ( name ) {
    alert("Here is your transportation ticket via the " + transport + ".\n" +
            "Welcome to the Cold Closures Cove, " + name + "!");
}
```

И следующее выражение

```
var getSubmarineTicket = buildCoveTicketMaker("Submarine");
```

Становится эквивалентным

```
var getSubmarineTicket = function ( name ) {
    alert("Here is your transportation ticket via the " + "Submarine" + ".\n" +
            "Welcome to the Cold Closures Cove, " + name + "!");
}
```

Таким образом, вызывая полученную функцию с параметром `"Mario"`, параметр `name` имеет значение `"Mario"`.

Comment: ох, спасибо, теперь понимаю!